# How to avoid malloc in this recursive function?

Tags: c, memory-management, recursion

I've got the following working (correct output) recursive fft implemented in C. I'm using malloc within the recursive function which is definitely causing some lost memory but I don't see how to avoid it. Most other recursive algorithms I've seen pass the same memory to recursive calls (in-place I think it's called) but I'm unable to do this one like that. A direct solution to this memory leak will be great but links to relevant material will also be much appreciated.

```
float complex *fft(float complex *in, int n, float complex w) {
  int i,j;
  if(fabs(crealf(w)-1.00f)<.0001f && fabs(cimagf(w)-0.00f)<0.0001f) {
    return in;
  }
  float complex *ine = malloc(n/2*sizeof(float complex));
  float complex *ino = malloc(n/2*sizeof(float complex));
  for(i=0,j=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(i%2==0){ 
      ine[j]=in[i];
    }
    else {
      ino[j++]=in[i];
    }
  }
  float complex *s = fft(ine,n/2,cpow(w,2));
  float complex *s1 = fft(ino,n/2,cpow(w,2));

  float complex *bad = malloc(n*sizeof(float complex));
  for (j=0; j<n/2; j++){
    bad[j] = s[j] + cpow(w,j) * s1[j];
    bad[j+n/2] = s[j] - cpow(w,j) * s1[j];
  }
  free(ine); free(ino);
  return bad;
}
```

Also is returning a pointer to memory allocated within a function considered bad practice since it leaves it to the caller to free that memory?

I tried to sign up to Code Review but the Sign Up button doesn't work on my ancient browser.

Comment: It's only bad practice if the caller doesn't free the memory. It's not uncommon for functions to allocate memory and letting the caller free it (see for example `strdup`).

Comment: you have forgotten `free(s) and free(s1)`

Comment: You are not freeing the s and s1 pointers even though your function is handing management of them to the caller. But more generally, you should re-consider the memory usage of this function. Lots of small mallocs are bad for performance. Since you know you will only recurse log2(n) times, you can allocate the entire buffer up-front and work on different parts of it as you recurse. Alternatively, consider which memory you can safely clobber - most fft algorithms require much less memory than this because they re-use memory when it is no-longer needed.

Comment: And of course, unless you're doing this purely as a learning exercise, I'd strongly recommend using one of the many existing fft libraries out there rather than rolling-your-own. There are lots of optimisations (both high- and low- level) which the libraries are able to exploit (e.g. switching algorithm by input size, vectoring, threading, L1/L2 cache management, ...)

Comment: Ah ok s & s1 now freed but still losing a smaller amount of memory. @Dave it's a learning exercise - can you please point me to a good library ?

Comment: the memory you would be losing is the first call you make also needs to free the result when it is done with it.

Comment: Other than the returned memory potentially leaking, you may also be suffering from memory fragmentation, which is a common problem with rapid malloc/free activity. As for libraries, there are plenty out there. LAPACK (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) and FFTW (http://www.fftw.org/index.html) are the ones which spring to mind. Both have a bit of a learning curve, though. There are also simpler ones when speed isn't so important.

Comment: Note that `free()`ing `s` and `s1` prior to returning is correct *only* when they are different from `ine` and `ino`, which it appears they may not always be.  It is important to avoid `free()`ing the same memory twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `bad`, since the calling instance of the recursive function does not know whether a recursive call returns the argument passed, or the newly allocated pointer `bad`. The other two pointers `ine` and `ino` are no problem, since they are always `free`d in the instance that allocated them.

I was in the midst of writing a solution which manages an array of `bad` pointers allocated which can be freed at the end of the program, when a better solution occurred to me.

**Add a new parameter** `int *newptr` informing the caller whether to `free` the pointer returned, since this pointer is not passed back down the recursion stack.

```
float complex *fft(float complex *in, int n, float complex w, int *newptr) {
  int i,j;
  int mem=0, mem1=0;                                    // added these flag vars
  if(fabs(crealf(w)-1.00f)<.0001f && fabs(cimagf(w)-0.00f)<0.0001f) {
    return in;                                          // no memory was allocated
  }
  float complex *ine = malloc(n/2*sizeof(float complex));
  float complex *ino = malloc(n/2*sizeof(float complex));
  for(i=0,j=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(i%2==0){ 
      ine[j]=in[i];
    }
    else {
      ino[j++]=in[i];
    }
  }
  // recursion starts here
  float complex *s = fft(ine,n/2,cpow(w,2), &mem);      // added extra arg
  float complex *s1 = fft(ino,n/2,cpow(w,2), &mem1);    // added extra arg

  float complex *bad = malloc(n*sizeof(float complex));
  *newptr = 1;                                          // flag memory allocated
  for (j=0; j<n/2; j++){
    bad[j] = s[j] + cpow(w,j) * s1[j];
    bad[j+n/2] = s[j] - cpow(w,j) * s1[j];
  }
  free(ine); free(ino);
  if (mem)
      free(s);                                          // free returned mem
  if (mem1)
      free(s1);                                         // free returned mem
  return bad;                                           // with newptr set
}
```

Comment: I would be interested to know why this was downvoted: be brave and say why, or post a better answer.

Comment: It wasn't me. Probably whoever downvoted the question. Your solution is worth a shot but the problem now is that if s and s1 are freed, the output isn't right.